# Get post first paragraph without html tag

Tags: get-post

please can someone help me the correct code to filter the first paragraph of any post without any form of html-tag in the source code.

i used 
function get_first_paragraph(){
    global $post;
    $str = wpautop( get_the_content() );
    $str = substr( $str, 0, strpos( $str, '

' ) + 4 );
    $str = strip_tags($str, '');
    return '

' . $str . '

';
}

in the function.php file

and  in the header where i want it to show but it left a blank space without any text showing there.

an help please i will appreciate.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create function using wp_trim_excerpt to grab the first paragraph of text and ignore images

```
function custom_excerpt($text, $raw_excerpt) {
  if( ! $raw_excerpt ) {
  $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
  $text = substr( $content, 0, strpos( $content, '</p>' ) + 4 );
  }
  // strip any images on the code 
  $text = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $text); 
  return $text;
add_filter( 'wp_trim_excerpt', 'custom_excerpt', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: @ExamPlaza how are you calling this function ?

Comment: sir i didn't get you

Comment: sir it didn't work for me. i used 

`<?php global $post; $content = $post->post_content; if(!empty($content)) {?> <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo strip_tags($content); ?>" /> <?php }?>`

it worked perfectly just that it pull the whole post instead of first paragraph only. is the any modification i can do to the code so that it show only first paragraph

Comment: @ExamPlaza - I have ask you how did you call my function ? you add my function on your functions.php and then how do you call my function on your theme files?

Comment: `i used <?php custom_excerpt($text, $raw_excerpt);?>`